# Javascript fundamental clarification needed

Tags: javascript

I know little bit C# and now I have started working with `JavaScript` and I got some problems in understanding the fundamentals.

Here is my code sample:

```
function BaseFunc(x, y) {
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
}

function DerivedFunc(x, y, z) {
    this.Z = z;
    BaseFunc.call(this, x, y);
}

DerivedFunc.prototype = new BaseFunc;   


 function Test() {
    var d = DerivedFunc(1, 2, 3);
    var b = new BaseFunc(4, 5);
    d.sayHello();
    b.sayHello();
}

DerivedFunc.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    alert("Result is: " + (this.X + this.Y + this.Z));
}
```

In the above code I am trying to make an inheritance.

Everything looks good until I reach the line `BaseFunc.call(this, x, y);` this line is supposed to call base function but what is the use of `this` in this context.
Is it just to satisfy the signature of method `call`, how does it work ?

Second question is, in javascript we can add anything dynamically,
In my case I am adding a `sayHello()` property and assigning it with an anonymous function.
like `DerivedFunc.prototype.sayHello`, am I adding a property/method to `BaseFunc` or `DerivedFunc`, as it is added to prototype it should be added to `BaseFunc` as I understand it. But when I execute the above code I get error that `sayHello` is not defined.

Can someone please clarify me about what is going wrong, thanks?

Comment: `var d = DerivedFunc(1, 2, 3);` This is one of the reasons [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/) go against using "class" in JavaScript in his [book](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0596517742/wrrrldwideweb): it's syntax correct, no error raised, but you may not got what you want. You may actually mean `var d = new DerivedFunc(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: @Passerby: There are a million programming errors that are syntactically correct and don't raise errors, but which don't do what the programmer intended. I don't know why people get so obsessed with this particular one, it's no worse than others.

Comment: You might benefit from reading the [MDN article about object-oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Comment: @ShrShr I "transformed" your code to a pseudo "Class-Oriented" code: http://pastebin.com/13JWhXkv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything looks good until I reach the line BaseFunc.call(this, x, y); this line is supposed to call base function but what is the use of this in this context.

It's there so that within the call to `BaseFunc`, `this` has the same value it has in the call to `DerivedFunc`, so that the lines `this.X = x;` and such in `BaseFunc` are assigning to the correct instance. (Calling a function setting a specific value for `this` is what the `.call` and `.apply` methods of functions do.)

> But when I execute the above code I get error that sayHello is not defined.

If it's `d.sayHello` where you're having the trouble, it's because you've missed out the `new` operator on the line `d = DerivedFunc(1, 2, 3);`. Since `DerivedFunc`, when just called as a function and not via `new`, doesn't have any return value, `d` will be `undefined`.

---

Note that the way you're doing inheritance, though common, has issues. The main issue is here:

```
DerivedFunc.prototype = new BaseFunc;
```

You're trying to use a function designed to create instances, and which accepts arguments, in order to create the prototype instance that `DerivedFunc` will assign to things. What then is `BaseFunc` supposed to do about the arguments that are missing? Then later, you call it *again* (from `DerivedFunc`) to initialize the instance. `BaseFunc` is doing double-duty.

Here's how you correct that, first the long-winded version:

```
function x() { }
x.prototype = BaseFunc.prototype;
DerivedFunc.prototype = new x;
DerivedFunc.prototype.constructor = DerivedFunc;
```

Or if you can rely on ES5's `Object.create`:

```
DerivedFunc.prototype = Object.create(BaseFunc.prototype);
DerivedFunc.prototype.constructor = DerivedFunc;
```

Now we're not calling `BaseFunc` to create the prototype, but we are still getting its `prototype` object as the underlying prototype of `DerivedFunc`'s `prototype` object. We no longer have the problem of what to do with `BaseFunc`'s arguments, and `BaseFunc` is only called in the way it's designed to be called: To initialize individual instances, not prototypes.

Naturally, rather than writing that for every time we want to have derived constructors, you'd have a helper script for it.

If you're interested in JavaScript inheritance hierarchies, you may want to look at my short [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) script — not necessarily to use, but to understand how these things work. The [page showing how to do things without the script](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/wiki/ComparisonWithPlainJavaScript) and comparing to doing them with the script may be particularly useful.

Comment: Crowder: Thanks Sir for ur answer I put new and it works for Derived but Why can't I call sayHello on BaseFunc since I added it by saying Derived.prototype.sayHello ?

Comment: @ShrShr: Because you didn't add it to `BaseFunc.prototype`, which is the object assigned as the prototype of instances created via `new BaseFunc`. Instead, you assigned it to `DerivedFunc.prototype`, so it's only available to instances created using *that* as their prototype (the ones created via `new DerivedFunc` in this case). While `DerivedFunc.prototype` uses `BaseFunc.prototype` as its prototype, they're separate objects, adding properties to `DerivedFunc.prototype` has no effect on `BaseFunc.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please go through the following. I hope it will give you some idea about inheritence and call()

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

    //inheritence
    function parent() {
        this.add = function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
        this.subtract = function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    }

    function child() {
        this.display = function () {
            alert(this.add(11, 23));
        }
    }

    child.prototype = new parent();         //child extends parent.... inheritence
    child.prototype.constructor = child;    //resetting constructor property

    var obj = new child();
    obj.display();

    /*
    .call() and .apply()
    They allow our objects to borrow methods from other objects and invoke them as their own
    */
    var person = {
        name: 'Kundan',
        display: function(name) {
            alert(this.name + ' welcomes ' + name);
        }
    };

    person.display('Dipa'); //Kundan welcomes Dipa

    var person1 = { name: 'Java Master' };
    person.display.call(person1, 'Sachin'); //Java Master welcomes Sachin
    //here person1 object is passed in the call function
    //if we are using call inside a function and want to pass the same function object then this is passed in call function
    /*
    We can pass more parameters as follows

    person.display.call(person1, 'a', 'b', 'c');

    The method apply() works the same way as call() but with the difference that all parameters you want to pass to the method of the other object are passed as an array.
    */
        person.display.apply(person1, ['a', 'b', 'c']);



</script>
```